# Issues with Latching switch using push button

Tags: switches, latch

I'm trying to make a latching power switch based off this schematic (source: [EDN](http://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4427218/Latching-power-switch-uses-momentary-pushbutton)) [image: push button latching power circuit]

I emulated the circuit in Falstad and everything works like it should ([link to simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+81.92041607667615+63+5.0+43%0AR+224+48+160+48+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ag+192+368+192+400+0%0Af+384+80+432+80+5+1.5%0Ar+256+48+256+192+0+10000.0%0Ar+336+80+336+192+0+10000.0%0Ar+432+256+432+320+0+100000.0%0Ar+176+240+320+240+0+1000000.0%0Aw+256+192+336+192+0%0Aw+384+80+336+80+0%0Aw+256+48+432+48+0%0Aw+432+64+432+48+0%0Aw+432+96+432+176+0%0Aw+432+176+432+256+0%0Aw+320+240+432+256+0%0Aw+432+320+432+336+0%0At+368+336+336+336+0+1+-4.9998349582619275+1.6504073151396936E-4+100.0%0Aw+432+336+368+336+0%0Aw+336+192+336+320+0%0Ac+176+256+176+320+0+5.3E-7+1.77464026279125E-4%0Aw+176+240+176+256+0%0As+176+112+176+192+0+1+true%0Aw+336+80+176+80+0%0Aw+176+80+176+112+0%0Aw+176+240+176+192+0%0Aw+336+352+176+352+0%0Aw+176+320+176+352+0%0Aw+192+368+176+352+0%0Aw+224+48+256+48+0%0Ar+512+240+512+336+0+3300.0%0Aw+432+176+512+176+0%0Aw+512+176+512+240+0%0Aw+512+336+512+368+0%0Aw+192+368+512+368+0%0Ao+23+64+0+35+0.001220703125+9.765625E-5+0+-1%0A)).

However, it doesn't work when assembled on a PCB. When I click the button, I see a sudden spike at Vout from 0 to 0.2V and then it quickly settles back to zero. I'm seeing no behavior that is similar to the simulation. I'm now starting to think I selected the wrong MOSFET/Transistor for the job, but I'm not sure which property would effect the circuit.

Here are some more details about my imlementation:

- Vs - LiPo Battery (3.9 to 4.2 V Nominal)
- Desired Vout - mirrors +Vs
- Mosfet - [FDN352AP](http://datasheet.octopart.com/FDN352AP-Fairchild-datasheet-93824.pdf)
- Transistor - [MMBT2222A](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MM/MMBT2222A.pdf)

Any thoughts? This is the first analog circuit I've built (simulated a few), so not really sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved. The circuit was failing due to a faulty isolation diode earlier in the circuit.